# Access token is empty with GuzzleHttp

Tags: php, microsoft-graph-api, guzzle

When I try to make a connection to Microsoft Graph with the following code:

```
$headers = [
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
    'Content-Type: application/json;odata.metadata=minimal;odata.streaming=true;IEEE754Compatible=false;charset=utf-8',
    'Preference-Applied: odata.track-changes'
];
$response = $this->guzzle->request('GET', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime=2017-12-12T00:00:00Z&enddatetime=2020-12-13T00:00:00Z'. ['headers' => $headers], ['debug' => true]);
```

Which gives me the error:
`Access token is empty`

And the debug gives me this:

> - About to connect() to graph.microsoft.com port 443 (#0)
> - Trying 40.126.9.112...
> - Connected to graph.microsoft.com (40.126.9.112) port 443 (#0)
> - Initializing NSS with certpath: sql:/etc/pki/nssdb
> - CAfile: /etc/pki/tls/certs/ca-bundle.crt   CApath: none
> - SSL connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_GCM_SHA384
> - Server certificate:
> - subject: CN=graph.microsoft.com
> - start date: Jan 27 19:09:45 2019 GMT
> - expire date: Jan 27 19:09:45 2021 GMT
> - common name: graph.microsoft.com
> - issuer: CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 2,OU=Microsoft IT,O=Microsoft Corporation,L=Redmond,ST=Washington,C=US
>
>   > GET /v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime=2017-12-12T00:00:00Z&enddatetime=2020-12-13T00:00:00ZArray
>   >     HTTP/1.1 User-Agent: GuzzleHttp/6.3.3 curl/7.29.0 PHP/5.6.40 Host:
>   >     graph.microsoft.com
>
> < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized < Content-Type: application/json;
>   charset=utf-8 < request-id: c82bfd7f-921f-40b7-a973-38b6630cb2c2 <
>   client-request-id: c82bfd7f-921f-40b7-a973-38b6630cb2c2 <
>   x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"West
>   Europe","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"5","ScaleUnit":"002","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_45","ADSiteName":"WEU"}}
>   < WWW-Authenticate: Bearer realm="",
>   authorization_uri="https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize",
>   client_id="00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000" <
>   Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000 < Date: Tue, 09 Apr 2019
>   08:08:39 GMT < Content-Length: 234

Somehow it does work in Postman when I give the same details however like you can see, the code after `Bearer` is empty. I did check `$this->getAccessToken()` and it definitely contains the token.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
        $headers = [
        "Authorization" => "Bearer". $token,
        'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
    ];

$response = $this->guzzle->request('GET', 'https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/calendarview/delta?startdatetime=2017-12-12T00:00:00Z&enddatetime=2020-12-13T00:00:00Z', ['headers' => $headers], ['debug' => true]);
```

You had a dot after your URL instead you needed a comma. Also your $`headers` array should be format like "`$key => $values`" relation to be passed in the guzzle request.

Comment: Ahh you're right I must have done it while playing around. But it did not solve the problem I'm still getting the same error only without debug information now.

Comment: you are getting that the token is missing?

Check the headers postman is using and add them as well. Probably you are missing `Content-Type: application/json` header, but postman can help you a lot in this cause it prefills them for you in the requests

Comment: I added the postman headers and even used print_r() to check it but unfortunately still the same error. The error I still get is "Access token is empty"

Comment: I just saw my stupid error and you editted when I wanted to comment haha